# Update OpenLayers setOverviewMap

Tags: openlayers

Is there a way to **add layers to an OpenLayers OverviewMap after it's been instantiated?** Adding a layer or layer array as a constructor prop doesn't work because at the time of loading, I don't have the layer when the map is created.

Comment: yes, you can add layer on different events also. just need to write **map.addLayer(yourlayer)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default an overview map will use the layers collection of the parent map, so adding to one also adds to the other.  Use `.setLayerGroup()` to give it a new collection then you can add to it without affecting the parent.

```js
  var ovControl = new ol.control.OverviewMap();
  var map = new ol.Map({
    controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([ovControl]),
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [500000, 6000000],
      zoom: 7
    })
  });
  var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      url: 'https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson',
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    })
  });
  var ovMap = ovControl.getOverviewMap();
  ovMap.setLayerGroup(new ol.layer.Group());
  ovMap.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

```css
html, body, .map {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```